# How do I express compassion in the case of sickness?

Tags: phrase-request

My question is as mentioned in the title. My try is

> Es tut mir leid, dass du krank bist.

Are there other more typical sentences?

Comment: Reopened because this clearly is not a translation request, a spell-checking request or a a request on proofreading. Would the community [**please take more care in choosing an appropriate close reason**](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1326/community-moderation-robo-reviews-dont-help-anybody)? Also see https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/what-is-a-phrase-request-and-when-do-we-accept-it-as-on-topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd not use it. Sounds weird to me to say "tut mir leid" for something that is not my fault. Search the site to find other opinions on this.

I'd rather say "schade / zu dumm, dass du krank warst [und nicht kommen konntest]" in retrospect, or, if the person is actually still sick, I'd use "Gute Besserung" ("get well soon").

Comment: Does it sound weird, even in a "brief" ?

Comment: In my opinion (I am a native German Speaker), it does not sound weird at all. It can be used both in written and spoken language. But the proposals made by Robert ("Schade") are maybe more typical.

Comment: @HussienChahin I'm getting confused here. Do you mean the German word "Brief" (letter) or the English word "brief" (briefing, presentation for conveying information)? Assuming the German Brief: again, I'd not use it; maybe for personal preference. "Get well" cards usually focus on the future and getting well, not so much on "sorry you couldn't do something cause you were / are sick". With that it would depend on the context of the letter: do you want to tell the sick person what they missed or tell them you care about them and hope they get better?

Comment: @Robert yeah sorry for the confusion,it's "brief" in german.As you said I want to show that I care for them and hope they become better

Comment: "zu dumm, dass du krank warst" sounds rather informal in my opinion

Answer (score 2):

> > Es tut mir leid, dass du krank bist
>
> Are there other more typical sentences?

What you have so far is fine, and more or less *"typical"* in such case. Though there could be many more wordings to express that same situaton, e.g.:

> > Schade, dass es Dir<sup>1</sup> nicht so gut geht.

---

> > Ich bin bestürzt zu erfahren, dass Du<sup>1</sup> krank bist.

Totally depends on what you really want to express regarding your feelings, or seriousness of the *illness*.
The latter would probably apply better, if you noticed that your friend is impacted with a serious disease like cancer or such, but not applicable for a simple cold.

---

There may be also variations on tense like

> > Es tut mir leid, dass Du krank **warst**. *(Perfect I)*

or

> > Es tut mir leid, dass Du krank **gewesen bist**. *(Perfect II)*

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>Note that *du* / *dir* is written with a capital *D* as a form of politeness and respect.</sub>